# Is there such a word as "Suppenkummer"?

Tags: vocabulary

I am actually a native speaker. My entire life I assumed that the word *Suppenkummer* did exist. Recently I spoke about it with a friend and she never heard of it. I did a research (Google, Duden) and also could not find it. Another friend of mine who is a German teacher also never heard of it.

I can not explain why I thought this term would exist. Just to be clear I do not mean *Suppenkasper*. That is what most people refer to when I ask them. So the bizarre thing about this is that I not only assumed the term would exist, I also think that I know what the meaning is, namely:

> When you ate too much (e.g. soup) and you start regretting it. (Maybe
>   because of a stomachache)

That is what I thought it would mean. Another possible explanation could be that I grew up bilingual (German and Russian). So I thought maybe I was thinking of a Russian term but subconsciously translated it into German.
But to be honest I can’t think of a word like this in Russian neither.

Have you ever heard this term? Could you think of any other word or combination of words I might be confusing *Suppenkummer* with?

Comment: Du bist jedenfalls nicht der einzige, der das Wort gebraucht, und auch nicht der erste, der es ins Web bringt: http://votographie.ch/japan-tag-6-die-gameholle-von-hiroshima/ (3. Absatz), https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.261087347264263.66148.193775080662157&type=3 (Kommentar unter dem ersten Posting)

Comment: Der Suppenhummer hat Suppenkummer :-)

Comment: Sarcastic comments like "Everybody is a native speaker." do not look good on this site. First of all, such a statement is trivially true, and secondly very impolite. Moreover, there should be room for different opinions; who says that there is a unique point-of-view which is correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I never heard *Suppenkummer*, but it feels like an actually valid localism. However, I’d like to offer an alternative explanation:

When I started working for my current employer, I learned the word **Suppenkoma** from my colleagues. Suppenkummer *could* be a mishearing of Suppenkoma.

Duden online actually [knows](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Suppenkoma) about this, but equals it to *Sättigungsgefühl*. While this is an aspect of Suppenkoma, I feel like it’s not a complete synonym, since Sättigungsgefühl does not include the drowsiness after eating (lunch), which the word emphasizes in my world.

Wiktionary does a [much better job](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Suppenkoma) at explaining it and includes the drowsiness aspect as main aspect. It puts “postprandiale Müdigkeit” as synonym, which is right on spot :)

Comment: *Suppenkoma* sounds a lot like *Fresskoma* =D

Comment: @Jan It probably is the SFW version ;)

Answer (score 7):

Die Frage, ob ein bestimmtes Wort existiert, wurde hier schon mehrfach gestellt, und immer ist die Antwort dieselbe:

### JA!

Immerhin hast du selbst dieses Wort benutzt. Wäre es kein Wort, hättest du es nicht als Wort in einen Satz einbauen können. Also: JA! Das Wort gibt es, und du selbst hast den Beweis seiner Existenz erbracht.

**Steht es im Duden? Im Wahrig? Im ÖWB? Sonstwo?**
Wen kümmert's? Die »Gitarrensaite« steht auch in keinem offiziellen Wörterbuch, und die »Windelbox« auch nicht. Trotzdem wird man in einschlägigen Geschäften genau diese Dinge bekommen, wenn man danach fragt.

**Hat das Wort eine Bedeutung?**
Die Bedeutung hängt vom Kontext ab. Wenn es dir gelingt, eine kurze Rede zu halten, in der das Wort *Suppenkummer* einen Sinn ergibt, dann hat es zumindest in dieser Rede einen Sinn, und wurde somit in dieser Rede völlig legitim eingesetzt.

**Ist es eine veränderte Wiedergabe eines anderen Wortes?**
*Suppenkummer* klingt - ohne Kontext - sehr nach einer Verballhornung von *Suppenkoma*, oder nach einer fehlerhaften Wiedergabe dieses Wortes. (Jemand sagt »*Suppenkoma*«, die Akustik ist schlecht und man war unaufmerksam, und schon rekonstruiert man aus den empfangenen Schallschwingungen stattdessen das Wort *Suppenkummer*, vor allem dann, wenn einem das ursprüngliche Wort nicht bekannt ist.)

Es kann durchaus sein, dass das so ist, aber das spricht dem *Suppenkummer* nicht den Rang eines existierenden Wortes ab. Es ist durchaus möglich, dass viele Menschen denselben »Fehler« machen, und dass sich der *Suppenkummer* zu einem vollwertigen Synonym des *Suppenkomas* entwickelt, oder dieses Wort vielleicht sogar irgendwann verdrängt. Beispiele dafür gibt es ja:

- *Hokuspokus* ist viel bekannter als *hoc est corpus* (»Dies ist (mein) Leib«; eine Floskel aus der christlichen Liturgie)
- Das »Heilbad Nr. 6« (*Balneario Nº 6*) in Palma de Mallorca ist wesentlich bekannter unter dem *falschen* Namen »Ballermann 6«

Deine Hinweise deuten zwar darauf hin, dass der *Suppenkummer* eine Verballhornung des Suppenkomas ist, aber das reicht nicht um völlig auszuschließen, dass damit vielleicht doch etwas anderes gemeint sein könnte. (Was genau, weiß ich nicht.) Du hast aber nicht gefragt, was das Wort bedeutet, sondern ob es existiert, und ich hoffe, ich habe diese Frage klar nachvollziehbar beantwortet.

Comment: Steht ja wohl im Duden, [Saite](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Saite). — Nur weil ich ein "Wort" benutze, ist es nicht direkt ein "Wort, das existiert". Dann kann ich ja Blödsinn sagen, wie Radidudibideschudewudu. Hey, für mich ist das ein Wort! Ok, Suppenkummer bestehst aus zwei sinnigen Deutschen Wörtern. Na gut, wie wär's mit "Kühlschrankhelfersyndrom". Macht kein Sinn? Egal. Es ist ein Wort. Auf den Rest geh ich nicht weiter ein, das ist alles Philosophie und hat nichts mehr mit Sprache zu tun.

Comment: Ich denke, das eigentliche Problem ist, dass es keine allgemein anerkannte wissenschaftliche Definition von *Wort* gibt, die in allen Fällen passt. Der Begriff ist praktisch, aber unscharf. Er muss für verschiedene Zwecke jeweils unterschiedlich präzisiert werden. Praktisch jede Frage, ob *X* ein Wort ist, bezieht sich auf den Grenzbereich der Definitionen und kann deshalb ohne genauere Beschreibung des Kontexts, in dem der Wort-Begriff präzisiert und angewendet werden soll, keine klare ja/nein-Antwort haben.

Comment: Ich finde wenn ein Wort beispielsweise im Duden (oder einem anderen Wörterbuch) vorkommt ist das schon recht aussagekräftig. Ansonsten sollte man eventuell auf "meta" über einen Konsens diskutieren um derartige Meinungverschiedenheiten in Zukunft vermeiden zu können.

Comment: Meistens kann man die Aufgabe, die "Nichtexistenz" des Wortes zu beweisen, auf den Gesprächspartner abladen, der diese (zum Vorteil des Neologisten) aus Trägheit nicht erfüllen wird.

Comment: @Em1 Danke! Und dass Gitarrensaite nicht unbedingt im Wörterbuch sehen muss ist auch klar, denn die Bedeutung erschließt sich intuitiv jedem, der weiß, was eine Gitarre und was eine Saite ist. Bei *Suppenkoma* verhält sich das ein wenig anders. Denn ich weiß zwar, was eine Suppe und was ein Koma ist, dennoch *kann* die Bedeutung eben sein, dass jemand nach dem Genuss einer Suppe in's Koma gefallen ist, oder aber dass er einfach die Plauze voll hat. Das erschließt sich aber nicht einfach. Dadurch, dass ich das Wort definieren kann, wird es aber nicht zu einem allgemein bekannten Begriff.

Comment: Ich denke aber, dass die Frage einfach zu einfach formuliert ist. Die Frage "Gibt es das Wort" wird (wie gesehen) zu einer ähnlichen philosophischen Diskussion führen wie "Dies ist keine Pfeife". Natürlich ist alles, was ich aus Klang in Schriftsprache überführen kann irgendwie ein Wort (wenn man "Wort" definiert als etwas das gesagt oder geschrieben werden kann). Ob es eine Bedeutung trägt ist aber eine ganz andere Frage. Man kann natürlich wortklauberisch philosophisch daherkommen oder eben nicht...

Comment: @bodycountPP Wenn die Frage »Was ist ein Wort« überhaupt irgendwo diskutiert werden sollte, dann auf Linguistics.SE oder auf Philosophie.SE. Meta.de.SE ist der falsche Ort, da es dort um Regeln für diese Seite geht.

Comment: Suppenkummer macht auf jeden Fall mehr Sinn, als Suppenkoma. Letzteres beschreibt weder ein Koma, noch rührt dieses von Suppe her. Das ist einfach nur Leberkäs.